# xcode iOS simulator opens file picker on startup but does nothing else

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan

[image: This] happens when I open the iOS Simulator on El Capitan - it opens a file picker and I can not do anything else. Closing the file picker closes the iOS Simulator. I can move the file picker dialog box and the iOS Simulator window freely around but only close the file picker, which also closes the iOS Simulator.

I couldn't find any settings for this nor can't I find any hints why this would happen...

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone chrome dressing on the window was removed in Xcode 6, so that is not a recent version of Simulator.

Please make sure you install a recent version of Xcode.app.  El Capitan supports Xcode 6.4 and newer.

Comment: yeah it's a bit weird, I think I'm going to completely remove it and reinstall it - I just saw on my iMac latest iOS simulator is also just called "simulator.app" and not iOS simulator.app